# Why is my object disappearing when use a boolean modfier

Tags: modeling, modifiers, boolean-modifier

I'm trying to use a boolean difference to engrave this design onto my mesh but whenever I do, the mesh disappears. I've tried applying all the transforms and modifiers, there are no flipped normals, I've tried lowering and raising the amount of polygons and at this stage I'm totally out of ideas [image] [image]

Comment: Did you check if both meshes are manifold?

Comment: hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/